# How can my service be notified when the Home or Back buttons are pressed

Tags: android, android-service

I would like to have my service perform something when the user presses Home or Back.
I'm not looking to override or block the normal behavior of these buttons, just get notified about them.

I need to get notify even when the activity that started the service is stopped.

Working with platform 17-19.

Is there any way? 
Can it be done by intent-filter or broadcast receivers??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Activities (and Fragments) will get these callbacks (onPause, onStop etc.). If your Activity is running, it can notify the service, but once it's in the background there is no way to do this.

Comment: I'm not looking to get these callbacks, I just asked if there some kind of system event/broadcast that I can listen to and act on.

Comment: It's not possible unless you develop a home screen replacement. In this case you will get notified when the user presses the home button.

Answer (score 0):

If the service is on you can use a broadcast by hooking into onPause or on onStop methods in the activity. if the service is not on I think you have to start it, do something, then end.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question the state of the activity that started the service is already stopped. I have no control of the activity the runs in the foreground when the Home/Back is pressed so I cannot hoop in to it's Pause and Stop callbacks.